# Music player (online/desktop) with ability to tag files (not ID3 tag)

Tags: music, media-player

I'm looking for a player (ideally Mac OS X or Android or online) which instead of playlist (you can play only one at time) has a concept of tags to organise songs.

So I can tag songs with as many tags as I want and then I can ask my player to play e.g. "childchood", "rock", "polish" tagged songs. It should be easy (1click) to add/remove tag from song and easy to filter songs by tags (e.g. simple text field).

I could find anything like this and even start thinking about writing one by myself. I cannot believe there is no such piece of software.

Comment: For which operating system? - - What about a solution that tags the file with a custom tag, and a player that allows listing tagged songs? -- Any requirements regarding the interface to add/manage tags? Is adding them manually okay, or do you need a GUI with checkboxes/autocomplete?

Comment: Ideally Mac OSX or Android or online. What do you mean by "custom tag"? Requirements are that it should be easy (1click) to add/remove tag from song and easy to filter songs by tags (e.g. simple text field). Autocomplete is nice to have, sure, so tags are not duplicated/similar.

Comment: The "tags" you describe with your question closely match the IDv3 genre tag. Players supporting IDv3 usually also offer to "play by genre", so that would match with your requirements. Have you checked for that?

Comment: @Izzy Do you know player to filter by multiple tags at same time and let play such list? Not sure if 'genre' is a good place, I'd like to put anything there, even band name, year (I know there are separate fields for that but I want to have it simple, not used so many of them). Additionally, music player must allow for *easy* adding/removing tag as I wrote, Ideally 1-click (to remove), tag name + enter to add...

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny Sorry, no. I rarely use any music players. I know some of them have an IDv3 tag editor integrated, but I doubt they meet your "one-click" requirement. Neither I'm aware of a player allowing you to filter by multiple tags. Afraid you're looking for the Unicorn here – but still, I might just have missed the perfect candidate.